# Access array content through loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a mysql query result which I have turned into an array with:

```
$row = customfunction_fetch_array($results);
```

This is how the `$row` array looks:

```
Array(
  [0]=> Array ([Fruit]=> apple [Count]=>4 [Season]=>Summer
  [1]=> Array ([Fruit]=> grape [Count]=>1 [Season]=>Fall
  [2]=> Array ([Fruit]=> apple [Count]=>3 [Season]=>Winter
  [3]=> Array ([Fruit]=> orange [Count]=>5 [Season]=>Spring
  [4]=> Array ([Fruit]=> apple [Count]=>45 [Season]=>All
)
```

What I'm trying to do is loop through the unique values of a specific field and save them to a new array.

```
$newArray =[];
foreach( $row["Fruit"] as $myFruits){
  $newArray[] = $myFruits;
}
```

I get a warning of:

> "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: @axiac It looks like it's his own function that fetches all the rows.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` doesn't return a multi-dimensional array. How can that be how the `$row` array looks?

Comment: yes it is my own function but i edited my post  for everyone's convenience.

Comment: Either way, the warning is about `$row["Fruit"]` not being an array. It is a string, so don't use `foreach` on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the array that you posted, there is no `$row['Fruit']`, there is `$row[0]['Fruit']`, `$row[1]['Fruit']` etc...

```
foreach($row as $values){
    $newArray[] = $values['Fruit'];
}
```

However, to get all the `Fruits` you can simply do this:

```
$newArray = array_column($row, 'Fruit');
```

Comment: This is wrong. `$row` is just one row of the table, not all the rows.

Comment: @Barmar: Not according to the array `print_r()` output in the question.

Comment: I misread it as `mysqli_fetch_array()`. I guess his `php_fetch_array()` fetches all the rows.